# Add comment inline with new item, or before

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml to insert some values into yaml files that i alredy have.
I am able to insert new items into the yaml file, but i can not insert comments.

This is what i'm trying to achieve

```
Resources:
  Statement:
    - Sid: Sid2
      Resource:
      # 1 - Account 1
      - item1
      - item # New Comment
```

This is the python code i'm using, but i'm not able to insert the item2 and the comments.

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_doc = """\
Resources:
  Statement:
    - Sid: Sid2
      Resource:
      # 1 - Account 1
      - item1
"""

yaml = YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_doc)
data['Resources']['Statement'][0]['Resource'].append("item2")
data['Resources']['Statement'][0]['Resource'].yaml_add_eol_comment('New Comment', 'item2', column=0)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Can I get some help on how to add the comment in line with the newly added item?

Thanks

Comment: You should always make a minimal reproducable example for your questions. Now I had to wade through a lot of irrelevant YAML before I found that the answer to your question  is *yes" (i.e. someone has some idea on how to achieve this).

Comment: Next time when you post a question, not only make a minimal example, but also include all of the code, including what you tried and failed to get to work.

Comment: Sorry for not exposing my issue in the best way. I tried to clean up my question. Thanks for any help you can give @Anthon